# (Database) Take the lowest date value from two columns and count the days

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, database

I have two columns where dates and times are recorded, the column "**DataDaInstauracao**" and "**DataDaDenuncia**". From these two columns I need to get the date with the shortest time in **days** of "DataDaInstauracao" and "DataDaDenuncia" and then throw the number of days on the screen.

The tables:

[image]

I already have a public List of data that I use to get the columns of this table already assembled:

```
// --------- graficos com base na TR_CRIME_AUTOR ---------
        public List<CrimeAutorModel> GetAllCrimeAutorModel()
        {
            using (IDbConnection cn = ConnectionAnaliseCriminal)
            {
                try
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    string query = "SELECT COD_CRIME_AUTOR"
                                   + ", DataDaDenuncia"                                  
                                   + " FROM dbo.TR_CRIME_AUTOR"
                                   + " WHERE DT_EXCLUSAO_LOGICA IS NULL";

                    return cn.Query<CrimeAutorModel>(query).ToList();
                }
                finally
                {
                    cn.Close();
                }
            }
        }

   public List<InqueritoModel> GetAllInqueritoModel()
    {
        using (IDbConnection cn = ConnectionAnaliseCriminal)
        {
            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                string query = "SELECT COD_INQUERITO"
                               + ", DataDaInstauracao"                                  
                               + " FROM dbo.TP_INQUERITO"
                               + " WHERE DT_EXCLUSAO_LOGICA IS NULL";

                return cn.Query<InqueritoModel>(query).ToList();
            }
            finally
            {
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

And I also have Ajax mounted on the controller that takes data and uses it to pass JS:

```
// --------- graficos com base na TR_CRIME_AUTOR ----------
        [HttpGet] public JsonResult AjaxGetAllCrimeAutorModel() => Json(new DashboardDados().GetAllCrimeAutorModel());

// --------- graficos com base na TP_INQUERITO ----------
        [HttpGet] public JsonResult AjaxGetAllInqueritoModel() => Json(new DashboardDados().GetAllInqueritoModel());
```

And I have the basis of the function:

```
async function shortestTimeDays() {

    let resultado, numberOfDays = 0;

    //chama o método ajax que trás todos os objetos
    try {
        const resposta = await fetch(`/Dashboard/AjaxGetAllCrimeAutorModel`);
        resultado = await resposta.json();
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("Erro ao realizar fetch");
        return console.error(e);
    }
  
    try {
          const resposta = await fetch(`/Dashboard/AjaxGetAllInqueritoModel`);
          resultado = await resposta.json();
      } catch (e) {
          console.error("Erro ao realizar fetch");
          return console.error(e);
      }
  
}
```

Now I would like to know how I should proceed in javascript to make my goal and be able to play the result on the screen.

[image]

```
<div class="blocoProcessos" style="margin-bottom: 2em;">
  <div style="width: 100%;text-align:center;">
    <div>
      <span style="font-size: 20px;font-weight: 400;">Tempo minimo fase pré-processual</span>
    </div>
    <hr class="hrBlocoProcesso" style="margin-bottom: 5px;margin-top: 10px;" />
    <div style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;align-items: center;">
      <span>Tempo (em dias)</span>
      <span style="font-size: 25px;">*</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by shortest date?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani I mean the number of days from one date to the next